# Expected behavior of overlayfs? Missing files from lower layer

Tags: filesystems, overlayfs

I'm trying to build a merged overlay structure where i can replace(offline, even with reboot) the lower layer. Somehow it is not working as expected to demonstrate my problem i used the following example:

```
mkdir lower upper work merged
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged
mkdir merged/test
getfattr -n trusted.overlay.opaque upper/test
umount merged
mkdir -p lower/test
touch lower/test/blub.txt
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged
ls -la merged/test
umount merged
touch upper/test/bla.txt
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged
ls -la merged/test
umount merged
rm -rf lower upper work merged
```

with following results:

```
root@linux:/data# mkdir lower upper work merged
root@linux:/data# mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged
root@linux:/data# mkdir merged/test
root@linux:/data# getfattr -n trusted.overlay.opaque upper/test
# file: upper/test
trusted.overlay.opaque="y"

root@linux:/data# umount merged
root@linux:/data# mkdir -p lower/test
root@linux:/data# touch lower/test/blub.txt
root@linux:/data# mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged
root@linux:/data# ls -la merged/test
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  3 18:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  3 18:30 ..
root@linux:/data# umount merged
root@linux:/data# touch upper/test/bla.txt
root@linux:/data# mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper,workdir=work merged
root@linux:/data# ls -la merged/test
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  3 18:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  3 18:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb  3 18:32 bla.txt
root@linux:/data# umount merged
root@linux:/data# rm -rf lower upper work merged
```

So basically I create a new folder on the empty merged overlayfs. As expected it creates this directory in the upper layer. But with the "trusted.overlay.opaque" set?

Now with that attribute set my changes on the lower filesystem will be hidden in the future. The changes are done offline so it should be valid?

tested on debian(4.19 kernel) and archlinux(5.10 kernel)

thank you for your time :)